How does one resample a 20m resolution satellite image to 10m resolution, such that it matches a native 10m resolution image?
I am trying to use Python to perform my GIS analysis.
Background:
I have 2 satellite images, one with 20m resolution and a second with 10m resolution.
Goal:
Have both satellite images at 10m resolution - with the same number of raster cells.
Problem:
I pass my file into my function to resample it and the 20m .tif file does not have the same number of raster cells as the 10m .tif file - even though it has been resampled to 10m.
They have matching extents.
Code:
import rasterio
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Function to vectorize a raster
def raster_to_vector(tif_file: str, output_file: str, band: str):

# Open the raster file
    with rasterio.open(tif_file) as src:
    # Read raster data
    raster_data = src.read(1)  # Assuming a single band raster
    # Get raster dimensions
    rows, cols = raster_data.shape
    # Calculate total number of raster cells
    total_cells = rows * cols

    # Vectorize the raster
    flattened_raster = raster_data.flatten()
    
    # Calculate number of pixels after vectorization
    pixels_after_vectorization = len(flattened_raster)

    # Export pixel values to CSV
df = pd.DataFrame({band: flattened_raster})
df.to_csv(f'{output_file}.csv', index=False)

print(f'Band: {band}')
print(f'Total number of cells in the raster: {total_cells}')
print(f'Number of pixels after vectorization: {pixels_after_vectorization}')

return pixels_after_vectorization

The printed output:
(10m original) Total number of cells in the raster: 352688
(20m original) Total number of cells in the raster: 350304

I indicated which output line belongs to which original .tif file.

Where in your code do you actually resample anything? What does the flatten method do? Is this code created by an "AI"?

That code is unrelated to the question you ask.

Correct, I figured it out yesterday and the problem has to do with the original images which were clipped using a shapefile. It appears as though clipping the 20m and 10m resolution images using a shape file will exclude pixel cells that are not contained within the shapefile explicity. Something like this, I am sure it is not quite correct so please feel free to correct me :)

Take a look at the up and downsampling example.
I'm resampling a 20 m image to 10 m. I have two Sentinel 2 bands covering the same area with different resolutions. I want to resample the 20 m to match the 10 m:
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

file_10m = r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/gisdata/Sentinel2/batch_downloads/S2A_MSIL2A_20220421T101601_N0400_R065_T33VWH_20220421T134744.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T33VWH_A035669_20220421T102238/IMG_DATA/R10m/T33VWH_20220421T101601_B02_10m.jp2"
file_20m = r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/gisdata/Sentinel2/batch_downloads/S2A_MSIL2A_20220421T101601_N0400_R065_T33VWH_20220421T134744.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T33VWH_A035669_20220421T102238/IMG_DATA/R20m/T33VWH_20220421T101601_B02_20m.jp2"

upscale_factor = 2

with rasterio.open(file_20m) as dataset_20m:
    resampled_data = dataset_20m.read(
    out_shape=(
        dataset_20m.count,
        int(dataset_20m.height * upscale_factor),
        int(dataset_20m.width * upscale_factor)
    ),
    resampling=Resampling.bilinear)
    transform_20m = dataset_20m.transform * dataset_20m.transform.scale(
        (dataset_20m.width / resampled_data.shape[-1]),
        (dataset_20m.height / resampled_data.shape[-2])
    )
    resampled_shape = resampled_data.shape
    


with rasterio.open(file_10m) as dataset_10m:
    data_10m = dataset_10m.read()
    transform_10m = dataset_10m.transform
    data_10m_shape = data_10m.shape

#The shapes and transforms are now the same for the 10 and 20 m images:
for x in [resampled_shape, data_10m_shape, transform_20m, transform_10m]:
    print(x,"\n")
    # (1, 10980, 10980) 

    # (1, 10980, 10980) 

    # | 10.00, 0.00, 499980.00|
    # | 0.00,-10.00, 6800040.00|
    # | 0.00, 0.00, 1.00| 

    # | 10.00, 0.00, 499980.00|
    # | 0.00,-10.00, 6800040.00|
    # | 0.00, 0.00, 1.00| 
    
#To save the resampled image:
out_resampled_file = r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/gisdata/Sentinel2/batch_downloads/S2A_MSIL2A_20220421T101601_N0400_R065_T33VWH_20220421T134744.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T33VWH_A035669_20220421T102238/IMG_DATA/T33VWH_20220421T101601_B02_20m_resampled_to_10m.tif"
with rasterio.open(out_resampled_file, mode="w", driver="GTiff", width=resampled_shape[2],
                   height=resampled_shape[1], count=1, crs=dataset_20m.crs,
                   transform=transform_20m, dtype=resampled_data.dtype) as dst:
    dst.write(resampled_data)



The problem had to do with the original two Sentinel 2 bands that I was looking at. Their extents do not match, despite having been clipped with the same shapefile.
The 10m resolution band extends slightly further than the 20m band. Even after resampling the 20m band to 10m and attempting to clip, there is still incongruity between the new resampled and reclipped images.
This does not solve my problem, but it does explain the problem I was having above.
